# What happens when I have 10 Yaroks out?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In the middle of a game right now. I have 10 [Yarok, the Desecrated](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bYarok%2c%20the%20Desecrated%5d) out. I play [Spine of Ish Sah](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpine%20of%20Ish%20Sah%5d).  How many triggers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Gatherer, Yarok has the following ruling:

> If you somehow control two Yaroks, a permanent entering the battlefield causes abilities to trigger three times, not four. A third Yarok causes abilities to trigger four times, a fourth causes abilities to trigger five times, and so on.

So, a tenth Yarok causes abilities to trigger eleven times.

Comment: Do they not effect each other at all? I thought pangarmonicon and yarok hit each other, wouldn't this be the same?

Comment: Panharmonicon and Yarok do not interact with each other that way either. Each one's ability says "that ability triggers an additional time", so you get one additional trigger for each Panharmonicon or Yarok.

Comment: Hmmm. I've been misled.